# Zaxcom Deva V users

Tags: field, recording, portable-recorder

Hi group
Any of you using a Zaxcom Deva V recorder?
Ive been offered a demo model for around $2000 from a dealer.
Besides the Deva V being an older model, Its still a $10000 plus recorder. There must be some kind of catch here, right?

Whats your opinion on this one?

Best wishes,

Mikkel

Answer (score 1):

We have a Deva 5.8 at work, and overall it's a great piece of gear. My biggest gripe with the 5.8, and I assume the 5 will have the same issue, is that it's a bitch to get the data off of it. Unlike the Sound Devices gear, it cannot act as an external hard drive with your computer (though I think there may be an adapter you can buy now that let's you do that...not sure). That means you essentially have to transfer the data twice! You mirror the data to a second drive (firewire drive, compact flash card or DVD-RAM), then you can transfer it to your DAW.

Oh, and that first transfer process from the Deva? Slooooooooooooow. Your best bet is to mirror while recording (yes, that is possible), and depending on how many channels you're recording, bit depth and sample rate, the unit might actually be able to keep up with a real-time mirror. Don't be surprised if it's not actually done mirroring data when you're done recording though. That means you need to leave the unit on to finish the job (or turn it back on again later). Transer is faster at lower sample rates, but since most of us record effects at 96k or higher...

If you can put up with the workflow annoyances, it's a great machine. I hardly ever use ours for those reasons though. I just don't always have the time to wait. The Nomad and the new Maxx units are far better thought out as far as data transfer afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Shaun. Those are deal breakers to me. It would really make me furious to wait, mirror etc.
Thanks alot. Wouldnt have thought of this being a problem. Thought that every recorder transfering data, was as easy as a SD unit.

Comment: It is not bad once you are in the habit of it.  For 2000, if the deck is not malfunctioning, then that is quite the deal.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mikkel,

Not a Deva user, but isn't it possible to hire the unit for a day and test it?
You could take it to another dealer and ask for a check up.

And you can always ask the dealer: why are you selling it?
If he's vague, 'step away from the vehicle' :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Arnoud. He is not being vague, and I have been buying great stuff from him before.
I guess I could ask for a test. Was just wondering if the unit was easy to operate, difficult to carry around etc.


Comment: Ah ok, can't help you with that.. Misunderstood your question I guess :)